# Can I bring a brand new, package iPhone into Costa Rica for another person?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cellphones, duty-free, costa-rica

Will I get in trouble with TSA/airport security for bringing a brand new, packaged iphone in my carry-on luggage from the USA to Costa Rica?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Post as an answer?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Hm, yeah. I hoped someone familiar with Costa Rican tariffs would come by with better information, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Neither TSA nor airport security are likely to care. Costa Rican customs, though, will probably want to have a chat about it to decide how much import duty you need to pay on the phone.

Be sure to bring the receipt so you can document its value, and choose the goods-to-declare lane on arrival, if there is one.